# OpenERP: Sum of Values in Loop

Tags: python, odoo

Im learner of Openerp May be it will be the basic question .
Below is my code:

```
def add_slab_info(self, cr, uid, ids, context={}):     
   sqty=2
 for qty in range(0,sqty):   
   area = (length) * (width)                                           
   Self.pool.get(object).create(cr, uid, {'product_id':value.product_id.id,
       'sno':no,'length':length,'width':width,'price':price,
       'area':area,
        })                
   self.pool.get('purchase.order.line').write(cr,uid,record_id,
        'product_qty':  sum(area),
        'product_field':product})
```

if sqty = 2 so it creates 2 lines

```
L W A 
1 2 2
1 2 2
    4 Sum(A)
```

I want to get the sum of area . could anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "sum of area"?

Comment: Please check my Code updated

Comment: Your code seems very incomplete and unclear to me. That's why I cannot formulate my suggestion as answer. Why don't you try to put the `write(...)` call in a separate loop. In the first loop you'll calculate your 'area_sum' variable as `area_sum += area` and in the new loop you'll use it in your `write(...)` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Hope this will help

```
def add_slab_info(self, cr, uid, ids, context={}):     
sqty=2
for qty in range(0,sqty):   
    area = (length) * (width)                                           
   Self.pool.get(object).create(cr, uid, {'product_id':value.product_id.id,
   'sno':no,'length':length,'width':width,'price':price,
   'area':area,
    }) 
  Sum_area += area               
  self.pool.get('purchase.order.line').write(cr,uid,record_id,
    'product_qty':  Sum_area,
    'product_field':product})
```